# Task start/stop handling using abstract classes

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, task, abstract-class

I have this code logic to handle my tasks:

```
public abstract class BaseJob{

    public bool Running { get; private set; }

    public CancellationToken Token => _tokenSource.Token;

    private CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;

    public virtual void Start()
    {
        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Running = true; 
    }
}
```

now when I inherit `BaseJob` I will have this situation:

```
public class CustomJob: BaseJob{

public MyEnum Status {get; private set;}

public StopRequested { get; set;}

public override async void Start(){

    base.Start();
    while(!StopRequested){
        await MyLongRunningMethod();
    }

    //base.Running = true but I can't access it here!
}

public async Task<bool> MyLongRunningMethod(){  
            await Task.Run(()=>{
                //more work
            },this.Token);
            //someWork

    return false;
}
}
```

As you can see I can't access `Running` to set it to false as soon as `myJob` finishes, and I want `BaseJob` to handle that.

What code logic changes must I bring to the base class in order to automatically detect when `myJob` finishes, and then finalize the task with `Running = false` without accessing the least from the inherited classes?

Comment: So why are you writing your own task object instead of using `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`?  You even tagged the TPL as being related, yet you're...not using it.

Comment: @Servy I have a program that's basically a bot, which runs loads of different tasks. That's why, I need a more complex structure than TPL task. Oh, by the way, I use the TPL tasks too, when I run the "job" inside the custom task.

Comment: And yet your "task" doesn't actually do anything that the TPL task doesn't do.  Your problem is best solved by having a method that does the work and returns a regular TPL `Task`.  If there's anything you need to do that that doesn't cover, you certainly haven't shown it.

Comment: @Servy there would be too much of code to show. I made it as simple as possible, but I ensure you that it does more than TPL task does.

Comment: Well then without even knowing what it's supposed to do, no one can really say how the class should be designed or implemented.  Of what you've shown, your requirements are best met by using the TPL task.  If there's something you need to do that you don't know how to do with TPL tasks, you'll need to describe what it is to get useful help solving it.

Comment: This whole implementation is based around the fact that the set must be private, the set being private means you just can't set the job to Runnig=false becasue that value can't be changed. If you do it via a function it override the problem of that value being changed froum outside because the function can be change. But the CustomTaks inherits from BotTaks which should be able to access IsRunning as its not from outside its from inside. So changing the private set to protected set would solve all this problems

Comment: @npo you are right. However, I just want `BotTask` to handle the `Running` flag.

Comment: @garryman That would be impossible unless you add some stop function or an event for job done.  But an event would be overkill and i don't think at all necessary for your case

Comment: @Servy added some more code logic to the question. Check it out

Comment: @garryman Still not seeing any reason to not just have a method that returns a `Task`.  A TPL task has an error, it can have a cancellation token, it has a status.  You can write a method that checks a cancellation token and runs an asynchronous operation while it's not canceled, and such a method can return a `Task` providing as much information to a caller of such an asynchronous method as your version of `Task` does.  (With the advantages that a TPL task has more features, and will work with various task-aware features in .NET and C#.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rewrite your abstract class to have an internal start method that can know when your job completes. Assuming your job is synchronous and takes no parameters:

```
public abstract class BotTask
{

    private bool Running { get; set; }

    public CancellationToken Token => _tokenSource.Token;

    private CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;

    public abstract void Start();

    protected void InternalStart(Action job)
    {
        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Running = true;
        job();
        Running = false;
    }
}

public class CustomTask : BotTask
{
    public override void Start()
    {
        InternalStart(MyJob);
    }
}
```

Comment: That was exactly the road I started approaching at the beginning. However, `Action job` is a task itself. A task with subtasks, all of which must make use of the cancellation token. Could you edit your answer and make an implementation of that, supposing `Action job` is a private Task method defined in `CustomTask` class? I got stuck at the part of implementing the `Task.Run ` method in the base class ( also note that that it must run in a thread pool, I don't want the UI stuck.

Comment: Can you show a code example of that in your question. It's sounding more and more like you want an actual `Task` from the TPL. Right now your `BotTask` isn't connected to any work so it's unclear how these could be nested as you describe.

Comment: Check the edit on Start override, and maybe you'll understand, if not, let's have a chat.

Answer (score 0):

Make Running set protected instead of private. This way it cant be accessed from outside but it can accessed by entities who inherit from BotTask

Comment: Sorry, but not my needing. Look at the edit, please. I want to access `Running` from outside to only `get` it, not `set`.

Comment: @garryman As you have it implemented currently, you cannot even `get` it from outside of the `BotTask` class. Sounds like you should change it to protected but with a private setter.

Comment: That's what I did in the edit. Anyways check the other answer and look at my comment, see if you can figure it out

Comment: Any reason why you can't do a protected set instead of a private set ?